# Choices must be iterable

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with Django and Python

I am facing the error `.from_hour: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.` Can someone help me understand what the error is? I know if I comment `from_hour` and `to_hour` it runs

Here is my code

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]


weekday_from = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, unique=True)
weekday_to = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
from_hour = models.IntegerField(choices=range(1,25))
to_hour = models.IntegerField(choices=range(1,25))

def get_weekday_from_display(self):
    return WEEKDAYS[self.weekday_from]

def get_weekday_to_display(self):
    return WEEKDAYS[self.weekday_to]
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory ..

Comment: @wim Do you mind explaining sorry.

Answer (score 7):

you must set values in ''

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('d', 'Draft'),
    ('p', 'Published'),
)
```

Comment: So I followed your guide and did `WEEKDAYS = [ ('1', 'Monday'), ('2', 'Tuesday'),...]` And still it doesn't work

Comment: I did `WEEKDAYS = ( ('1', 'Monday'),('2', 'Tuesday'),
        ('3', 'Wednesday'),
        ('4', 'Thursday'),
        ('5', 'Friday'),
        ('6', 'Saturday'),
        ('7', 'Sunday'),
        )
`

Comment: Come on people, the error was in the `from_hour` field, quit messing with the WEEKDAYS. Try (untested): `[(n, str(n)) for n in range(1, 25)]`

Comment: your range is overflow for numer choices

Answer (score 5):

The error is related to `from_hour`. You should provide a collection of tuples like `from_hour = models.IntegerField(choices=[(x, str(x)) for x in range(1,25)])`. And I think you should do the same for the `to_hour` field.

Comment: Thank you do you mind explaining why you can't do what I did

Comment: The error message says it all. You have to provide an iterable of tuples composed of the actual value and human-friendly representation, like.

Answer (score 3):

you must use **WEEKDAYS.choices** in choices attr, change this line:

```
weekday_from = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, unique=True)
```

to

```
weekday_from = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS.choices, unique=True)
```

Comment: WEEKDAYS  is list and it doesn't have choices attr then why this WEEKDAYS.choices?
Any source?